# Visual 2017 Form Designer Failing On "Can't Find Class Error" - However, The Class Exists

Tags: visual-studio, winforms

I am adding some more control to a win form I created that runs from a .dll

The project loaded fine, after I made some changes to the form in the form visual designer, compiled and then tried to open the form... I was fronted with this error screen.

[image: The error screen presented on the form designer]

It is complaining because it can't find the **NoButtonsTabControl** class.

The NoTabControl.cs class:

```
namespace TFG_Tools {

// Extend TabControl Class to provide a multi layer canvas with hidden tabs or buttons
public class NoButtonsTabControl : TabControl {
    public NoButtonsTabControl() {
        Appearance = TabAppearance.FlatButtons;
        ItemSize = new Size(0, 1);
        //SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed;
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        // Hide tabs by trapping the TCM_ADJUSTRECT message
        if (m.Msg == 0x1328) m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
        else base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    }// end NoButtonsTabControl class

}
```

The start of the main form class looks like this...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using ENSED;
using System.Globalization;
using Win32;
using WindowsEnv;

namespace TFG_Tools {


public partial class TradePanelForm : Form {
    //loaded as master
    private bool isMaster = false;
    public void SetAsMaster() { isMaster = true; }

    ...
```

Why has this suddenly just happened now, so frustrating. I am only intermediate with c# and visual studio. I only used it for this project to create the winform.

How do I tell the designer where this class is, so this error stops appearing?

The funny thing is, it worked fine before, with this arrangement! And if I compile the code, it works, and all the form elements are there.

It's just the designer which is dying atm.

P.S I also moved this project over from Virtual Studio 2015

Thank you.

Comment: I saw this a couple of times, when moving custom controls classes from the root directory of the Project to a new Folder (give or take what is shown here). Usually, cleaning the Solution/rebuilding the Solution solves the problem. Sometimes the NameSpace of the class is changed, when creating the class directly inside the sub-folder. Or it did. IIRC, the more recent version of VS doesn't do it anymore. Sometimes it's instead a satellite assembly (a dependency) that goes *out of sync*, when you move things around. Cleaning/Rebuilding usually solves this too.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did the clean / rebuild, but the error is still showing unfortunately. The thing is, I didn't rename and classes or name spaces. And It was working when I opened the project with the class in a sub folder.

Comment: Verify that all the projects/dependencies have the same bitness (all use the same target Platform in Project/Properties/Build). Check the dependencies in the Solution properties. Still bad? Try to remove the Control(s) from the Form, save and then add them back with the same name. If it's still a no go, try then to close VS, delete everything inside the `obj` directory in the *affected* Project(s), restart and rebuild.

Comment: You should be troubleshooting TradePanel.cs. Can you show the designer source code to that?

Comment: It is very large, the panel has a lot of controls, do you still want me to show it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution to this was weird.

1. close down all open windows in your project
2. Select the "any cpu" profile
3. go build->clean solution
4. Then build->rebuild solution
5. Re open your form designer

This worked for me, and hopefully will clear this mess up each time it pops up.

I have 2 profiles, a 32bit and 64bit profile so I can compile the dll to both.

Something must break in the designer when I switch to these profiles to build the project.

Hopefully this saves time for others.